# Aws cloud watch log insight vs Aws Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have implemented some queries and dashboards where I used cloudwatch logInsight. I have used sample queries where I used parse, fields, aggregate functions etc.

I am curious if we need complex queries like joins, windows functions etc, can we use Loginsight query language to create our scenarios just as done in SQL? I didn't find any good examples on docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Also I read Cloudwatch log are [six times](https://www.transposit.com/devops-blog/incident-management/2019.12.13-querying-cloudwatch-logs-with-athena/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20a%20number%20of,that%20support%20JDBC%20and%20ODBC.) expensive as compare to aws athena.

Is there any suggestions on complex monitoring what is the best way to do monitoring in aws?

Comment: and how did it work out? I have the same question right now.